# How store the data in Database from AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

The following shows my piece of code.

```
$.ajax({
 type:'POST',
 dataType: JSON,
 url: 'http://localhost/UPLOAD-THIS/public/api/place-order',
 data: {"order":[{"id":2,"restaurant_id":2,"item_category_id":1,"name":"Burger","price":"10.00","image":"/assets/img/items/1570619770Fblsy6snNM.png","is_recommended":1,"is_popular":1,"is_new":1,"desc":null,"placeholder_image":"/assets/img/items/small/1570619770Fblsy6snNM-sm.png","is_active":1,"addon_categories":[],"quantity":1},
       {"id":3,"restaurant_id":2,"item_category_id":1,"name":"Pizza","price":"20.00","image":"/assets/img/items/1570619787yieN7hwXCQ.jpg","is_recommended":1,"is_popular":1,"is_new":1,"desc":null,"placeholder_image":"/assets/img/items/small/1570619787yieN7hwXCQ-sm.jpg","is_active":1,"addon_categories":[],"quantity":1}],
           "coupon":[],"location":"Campus","order_comment":null,"total":{"productQuantity":2,"totalPrice":30},"method":"Wallet","payment_token":""},
 success: function(e) {
   alert(success);
 },
 error: function(e) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(e));
 }
});
```

The above data is dummy. 
I want to know how you can pass the data in such a way that it stores in the database.

For ex: "id" should be fetched from a form which is filled and store in Database.

Comment: So, are you looking for help in extracting data from a form, or help in storing that data in a database?

Comment: You'll need some code in a file `UPLOAD-THIS/public/api/place-order/index.php` that uses `$_POST` to process the incoming data. Then trigger this ajax and check your response (also you use `success: function(e) {`, so the variable is `e`, but you try to alert `success`, which is seemingly undefined).

Comment: console.log(data); first you debug this.

Comment: @PHP I did and I'm getting the data which I actually want to store.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan Storing the data in database. I just want to know how to write the "data" field syntactically, so that the data is referred from the form filled

Comment: What you are getting for `request->all()` on your controller method for `http://localhost/UPLOAD-THIS/public/api/place-order` url  post request?

Answer (score 0):

#### How to POST data to your backend and store it in the database:

You would need to:

1. Extract the data from the front-end using `JavaScript`
2. Include it in your POST request.
3. Catch and handle the request in `PHP` to store it in the Database.

#### Example:

This is a single *PHP* file sample (without full page refresh),
but you may need to change the parts `YOUR_DATA_HERE`,
`DATABASE_NAME_HERE` and also `root` (which is the user-name in `PhpMyAdmin`).

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // Escape possible HTML tags:
  $content = htmlspecialchars($_POST['myContent'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE);

  // Database connection.
  // (Allows data to take 64 KB using "65536" constant)
  $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=DATABASE_NAME_HERE', 'root', '');
  $db->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, text VARCHAR(65536))');

  // Storing new record.
  $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (NULL, :text)');
  $query->bindValue(':text', $content);
  if ($query->execute()) {
    $response = 'Successfully stored: ' . $content;
  }
  else {
    $response = 'Error: ' . join(' ', $query->errorInfo());
  }

  exit($response);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form#my_form_id').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var myContent = "YOUR_DATA_HERE";
      var url = '#';
      $.post(url, {'submit': true, 'myContent': myContent}, function(response) {
        alert(response);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="center" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 150px;">

    <form id="my_form_id">
        <input type="submit" name="Send">
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> **Notes:**
>
> 1. The `$.post(...)` method is a shorthand for `$.ajax({type:'POST', ...})` (they are both AJAX).
> 2. If you want to store your data without any change, then remove the `htmlspecialchars(...)` method usage (e.g. `$content = $_POST['myContent'];`).

Comment: I don't think this works as I want a AJAX call method for my project. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but the `$.post(...)` method is a shorthand for `$.ajax({type:'POST', ...});` (they are both AJAX).